# Benefit of using pretty urls on search results with content Noindex?

Tags: seo, search, noindex

Google doesn't want thin content like search results pages to be indexed. So I use noindex on all those search results on my website.

Then is there a benefit using pretty urls like below.

https://www.example.com/search/cat/

Over this:

https://www.example.com/search/?search_text=cat

other then look and easy of use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google suggests "pretty URLs" because making them more readable by humans is better for user experience. If you're not indexing those pages, then users will not see them in search results. So you don't need to change their URL structure since you won't be "eligible" for the benefit anyway.